# Prototype function calling an object undefined

Tags: javascript, game-physics, collision, platform

I am trying to make a collision function for my new platformer game and I came across an error when making my collision prototype function.

```
platforms = [];
var newPlatform = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x,
    this.y = y,
    this.width = 50,
    this.height
}
var platform1 = new newPlatform(10, 100);
var platform2 = new newPlatform(50, 50);
platforms.push(platform1);
platforms.push(platform2);
var player = {
    x:100,
    y:305,
    width:80,
    height:120,
    velocity_y:4
}
platforms.prototype.collision = function(player) {
    return (this.x < player.x + player.width && this.x + this.width > player.x && this.y
            < player.y + player.height && this.y + this.height > player.y);
}

for (let i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
    if (platforms[i].collision(player)) {
        player.velocity_y = 0 ;
    }
}
```

This gives out an error that reads "Cannot set property 'collision' of undefined" does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Your variable `platforms` is a global array. Assigning to it's prototype is not a good idea, and also it won't work the way your code expects it to work. You need to put that `collision` function on the `newPlatform` prototype, because that's how you're using it.

Comment: This seems to be javascript. Why are you also using the java tag?

Comment: isn't java a short version of the world javascript? or is it another programming language?  Also, you said making it a global array is a bad idea, what array method do you prefer?

Comment: No, java is it's own language. It's akin to saying you need help with your car when you are actually needing help with your carpet.

Comment: Java and Javascript are entirely different languages. The comparison I like is that Java is to Javascript as Car is to Carpet. They share some letters, but little else.

Comment: @Pointy you should post that as an answer since it solves the issue